# How to split a file containing JSON Array into multiple chunks?

Tags: java, json

I have a class as follows:

```
class MyClass {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  //getter and setter
}
```

And I have list of MyClass objects, Say `List<MyClass> objects`. Now I want to write these objects into a JSON file, something which looks like this:-

```
[
{
"field1": "abc1",
"field2": "xyz1"
},
{
"field1": "abc2",
"field2": "xyz2"
},
{
"field1": "abc3",
"field2": "xyz4"
},
//so on
]
```

Now, if the size of the file is more than 100KB,  then I need to split this into multiple chunks (less number of chunks as possible) so that every chunk is just about less than 100KB and contains valid JSON.

Lets assume that above file exceeds 100KB then I need to split into multiple chunks as follows:

```
chunk1.json
    [
        {
        "field1": "abc1",
        "field2": "xyz1"
        },
        {
        "field1": "abc2",
        "field2": "xyz2"
        }
    ]

chunk2.json    
    [
        {
        "field1": "abc3",
        "field2": "xyz3"
        },
        //....
    ]
```

After that I can process the file one by one. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your API call should limit the number of items returned, and allow you to page through them. Sounds better than a limit of 100K where each chunk would always have a different number of records

Comment: You could pre-process the List and calculate the number of bytes needed for each item, and split the List as needed to serialize each subList.  That could turn into an interesting problem to get as close to the max file size to minimize the number of files.  But why the size limit?

Comment: simply limiting the number is not enough, since the fields contain string, it could expand the size of a single object to infinity in theory. this task requires some estimation of size of string eventually generated, with consideration of file system block size, and it could be tricky.

Comment: I need to call an external REST API thats takes multipart form data and there is size limit on the file.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr if that's a real use case, then you have a point, but it may not be. In any case, you could make each page not always have the same number of items

Comment: What is so difficult about splitting it and what have you tried?

Comment: Splitting is easy but it gets tricky to maintain as JSON. Would have been easy for a normal CSV file for example

Comment: Is there any performance requirement?  For example, List contains 100 items, so just make 100 calls instead of 5 calls with 20 items.  If there is no dependency between the items, then could also make 100 concurrent calls with an Executor with a reasonable thread pool size.

Comment: It will work, but i guess it is a huge performance hit. There could be much better solutions

Comment: this question does not deserve a downvote, as it's in fact a tricky question with a seemingly easy disguise.

Comment: Please upvote if at all question makes sense. Have done enough research, but was't able to find a right solution

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String summary = "";

    for(int a = 0; a<100000; a++) { 
        String current =  "\r\n" + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new MyClass());

        if((summary + current).getBytes("UTF-8").length>100000) {
            System.out.println("Overload 100 kb!");
             printFile(summary);
            summary = current;
        }
        else 
            summary = summary + "\r\n" + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new MyClass());
    } 
}

public static void printFile(String string) throws IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss_SSS"); 
    try(  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Chunks\\" +sdf.format(new Date()) +".txt" )  ){
        out.println( string );
    }
}
```

Consider UTF-8 as a choice.
Split happens taking count the byte[] lenght so 100000 byte are 100kb.

For the serialization I've used a standard Jackson approach, this is the maven dependency:

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

...and finally the simple Pojo class:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }
    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
    public MyClass() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: The solution is clearly super easy for your arrays using Jackson to retrieve them from file like MyClass[] myObjects = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class); happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The exact implementation may depend on the serialization framework used (have a look at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), it is pretty easy to use), some may offer a specialized streaming API that can achieve something like this.
In the scenario that you are describing, a much simpler solution could be used though:

Serialize each instance in a for-loop and collect Strings in a buffer (e.g. StringBuilder or you go straight to an OutputStream). However, before you append a String to this buffer, you can check if size of your buffer + size of the new String exceed the 100kb. The only piece missing now are a few characters for start ( [ ), separator ( , ) and end ( ] )

(For the size calculations to be correct, you may have to convert the strings to bytes since characters like Äφς will take up more than one byte. Maybe this is already handled by your JSON framework)

You could of course do the serialization manually, but especially if your strings can contain characters like quotes ( " ) you could end up writing a lot of code until the JSON format is correct.

[edith: as others have pointed out, if the strings could be longer than 100kb it is not really possible to follow the specification]